# Executing npm run dev in Laravel 5.6 project halts at 95% emitting

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

I'm having an issue with laravel-mix, using Laravel 5.6. Every time i execute ***npm run dev***, the console execution stops at 95% emitting:

> @ dev C:\Users\ricky\Dropbox\Projects\52-TARCS\src\tarcs
>
> npm run development
>
> @ development C:\Users\ricky\Dropbox\Projects\52-TARCS\src\tarcs
>
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
>
> 95% emitting

Created a clean Laravel 5.6 project, executed **npm install** and then **npm run dev**.

I've been searching online and found many people with the same issue that solved it specifying the public path in **webpack.mix.js**:

```
mix.setPublicPath("./");
```

or

```
mix.options({
    publicPath: './'
});
```

In my case haven't been able to solve the problem.

My current webpack.mix.js settings:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.setPublicPath("./"); //mix.setPublicPath("./public");

/*mix.options({
    publicPath: './' //publicPath: './public'
});*/


mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');
mix.sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

My system specs:

- Windows 10 x64 (version 1803);
- Node: 10.0.0;
- NPM: 5.6.0;
- Laravel 5.6;

How can i solve my issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally figured out my problem!

I'm using Dropbox to store all my projects, and since i have two accounts linked (Personal and Business), Dropbox creates a symlink to the new folders (Dropbox (Personal) and Dropbox (Business)). This somehow is causing my issue...

From [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/help/business/folder-name-change):

> If your team members already have Dropbox installed on their
>   computers, all files and most applications will automatically point to
>   the new work Dropbox folder and subfolders. Dropbox will create a
>   hidden symlink that points to the new Dropbox folder from the old
>   location. Fresh installs don’t require this, as the Dropbox folder is
>   created with the business name from the beginning.
>
> Applications with absolute paths might need to be tested individually,
>   so we strongly encourage you to test your existing configurations
>   before the desktop application is updated.

I simply unlinked my business account and started using the main Dropbox folder. Everything is working as expected.
This was the quickest way to solve my problem, but the ideal would be to get both my Dropbox accounts linked. I'll check how to do that and update the answer with details.